# How to implement search suggestion in Entry in Xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.entry

I need to implement a suggestion box and for that purpose I placed one Entry to accept keyword and exactly below that I took Listview to display suggestions. Listview has already DataSource and some number of entries in it. Now I want to implement it like-

"Example, if the key words are:

- Milk
- Meat
- Cream

and as user types in ""m"", Cream is filtered out and only Milk and Meat are shown because they start with ""m"". As user types in ""mi"", Meat is also filtered out and only Milk is shown."

Answer (score 2):

Here You Go

```
       var list = new List<string> { "Milk", "Cream", "Meat" };
        var myListView = new ListView();
        myListView.ItemsSource = list;



        var entry = new Entry();
        entry.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text))
            {
                myListView.ItemsSource = list;
            } 

            else
            {


                myListView.ItemsSource = list
                        .Where(x => x.ToLower()
                           .StartsWith(entry.Text.ToLower()));
            }
        };

        MainPage = new ContentPage()
            {
                Content = new StackLayout()
                {
                    Children = { entry, myListView }
                }

            };
```

Comment: Hi TheMoFaDe, This is really great solution but I am facing one issue in that, it is showing results only for small case letter and not for Capital one. It should not case sensitive. If user enters "m" or "M", it should give list of all items starts with "m" or "M" and vice versa.

Comment: I solve it by replacing   myListView.ItemsSource = list.Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith(entry.Text)); -----with----- myListView.ItemsSource = list.Where(x => x.StartsWith(entry.Text)); ----- but it is case sensitive. I don't know how to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it case insensitive by changing it to the following:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = list.Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith(entry.Text.ToLower()));
```